# Powerpoint: Export Images For Use With pdfLatex

Tags: pdf, png, powerpoint

I need to implement several images which exist in `Microsoft Powerpoint` into a `latex` document.  The images are detailed.

Would anyone have suggestions for a method which will improve resolution over the standard raster export or will automatically crop down to a selection unlike the standard vector export?

### Raster option: `.png`

Selecting the objects and right clicking to exporting as `.png` produces terrible results, as the default export resolution of `Powerpoint` is not high enough.

Export resolution can only be increased in `Powerpoint` by editing a registry value, to my knowledge. This is not possible for me, due to work security policies.  Obtaining new software is also quite difficult.

### Vector option: `.pdf`

Printing to `.pdf` prints the whole slide.  I would like to print only a selection or a very easy method to autocrop the edges down to the minimum.

Comment: For a raster solution, I make the image as big as it will fit on my screen (PC), and do a screen capture with `CTL-ALT-PrtScn`.  Then I copy the buffer (`CTL-v`) into graphics editing software, crop the extraneous stuff, and save it as a raster image.  The resolution seems adequate for most situations.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Print screen does not have enough resolution.

Comment: A much more labor intensive variant on my earlier suggestion is to fit subsections of the image into the screen resolution and do as I said earlier. Then, the added difficulty is to crop the images at exactly the right spot, before remerging them.  I must ask, though, what is your output medium?  Paper?  Projected screen?  Unless one is printing things like blueprints, posters, or glossy PR for customers, the output medium's resolution is usually no finer than a hi-res screen.

Comment: Even if you print the whole slide, once you have the pdf image, you can `clip` it in `\includegraphics` and select only the fragment you need.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Oop.  The print-screen issue was Simulink-related, not powerpoint related.  I'm mixing my issues.  Printscreen is fine, aside from needing to zoom-center-printscncopypasta-crop-save for each image rather than simply save for each image.

Comment: @kando Well, yes, there is no free lunch (that I am aware of).  Bill Gates saw to that!

Comment: @Ignasi This is similar to the printscreen method.  I should have specified that I was hoping for a 1-stop shop to export to a high-res or vector image which was cropped to a minimum without the need for fine tuning.

Comment: You can use this method to crop: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/17423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to you to print to .pdf and then use a tool to select the area you need and cut it from the pdf. Then import the pdf to you latex

Comment: Some have mentioned that increasing the size of the slide can improve its resolution, but this sounds like a dirty method.  Do you ever do this?  I'll also have to see if our `.pdf` reader has crop capabilities.

Comment: Do you know a method to automate the crop to base minimum? Is this what the `standalone` package can be used for? I don't always completely understand it's original intentions. (I use `standalone` for creating section and subsection files in hierarchal format; I have not used it for creating `standalone` images.)

Comment: @kando Not `standalone`. The command line tool `pdfcrop` on the other hand, does exactly that.

Comment: In my macbook i've used the standard image viewer to cut pdf. You can find it in the tool bar. I already did it with ubuntu, but i don't remember the tool i used :(

Comment: A vector image was best, but I still need to find a `Windows` tool which will crop the `.pdf` down to the minimum.  Any suggestions? (I have Foxit PhantomPDF [Standard Edition] - it seems to retain any crop data in history, when I really want to remove all but the crop data.)

Answer (score 2):

In Lyx page, you can find [Metafile to EPS Converter](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter) software. Once installed you can copy a figure from PowerPoint, paste into MetafiletoEPSConverter and obtain a perfectly cropped eps file.

[image]

Later on with epstopdf, eps2pdf or imagemagick you can obtain the corresponding pdf file.

[image]

Comment: This is a good start, but this requires several steps and several softwares.  For steps, I'm looking for the 1-step process, if possible.  For softwares, all softwares will need to be risk assessed by my company.  Risk assessment is a process which can take months, even if it shouldn't.

Comment: At least in combination with modern PowerPoint 2016, this tool just embeds a raster graphic into the EPS file, so scalability and accessibility are lost.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you created the diagram with the powerpoint tools.

**1)** Draw the diagram

**2)** Right mouse extended select just you diagram, not the entire slide.

**3)** Left click INSIDE of one of the outlined pieces of the diagram.

**4)** Choose `save to file` `as a *.png` to the folder with the *.tex file.

**5)** Now just use `\includegraphics{filename}` and just the portion of the slide which you highlighted will be displayed.

Note: When I was teaching my *Technical Writing Using LaTeX* course, I would have the students use `PowerPoint` as a graphic file conversion tool, since you can drag and drop almost any graphic into `powerpoint` and then export it out as a `*.png`