# PowerPoint picture in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

What is the best way to export a power-point graphic (block diagramm and some text within the graphic; some parts are transparent) to use it in `LaTeX`?

I tried to save one slide as `.pdf` and import it via:

```
\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 80mm 20mm 5mm, clip,width=130mm]{test.pdf}
```

It works, but it is trial and error to find the right trim settings.

Is there a better way to do it? Probably export as `.jpg` is enough for a scientific journal? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think this can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254705/1952

Comment: The only thing that should be submitted as a .jpg is a photograph.  If you *really* have to export as raster graphics, use a lossless file format, as .jpg introduces horrible artefacts in hard-edged images such as diagrams

Answer (score 3):

I would say export as pdf and use a graphical pdf editor to trim it so that you see what you trim without having to recompile. I am on a Mac and here the native pdf viewer can be used for it but there must be alternatives for all operating systems I would assume.

Comment: Normally, Inkscape can do it.

Comment: Do they actually remove the stuff outside the trimmed/cropped area, or are they only hiding it? Meaning even after cropping the original image is still present.

Comment: I *think* that you can do both in Inkscape. Setting the bounding box and/or deleting elements.

Comment: @Rmano is right - delete the objects you don't want then you can usually set the bounding box by: select all (ctrl+A), document properties (ctrl+shift+D), "resize page to current drawing or selection".  Sometimes a white box sent to the back is needed to fine-tune things.